# MVC Durandal app doesn't work when deployed to IIS

Tags: iis, durandal

The platform is IIS on Win8.1

The project is created from the Durandal project template. No changes are made, and the project is run: the Durandal start kit appears in a web browser.

The project is deployed to a folder D:\Client

IIS manager is used to map a virtual application off the default web to D:\Client. The app pool for this is specified as DefaultAppPool which on my machine is set to FX4.0 and runs with my user credentials. Deliberately setting it to FX2.0 produces a 502 as expected. This implies that the FX version is not the problem.

`http://localhost/Client` produces the splash screen but the app hangs there. Using the browser's own debugger reveals that main has NOT been executed.

Loaded:

- bootstrap.js
- jquery-1.9.1.js
- knockout 2.3.0.debug.js
- require.js

Has anyone experienced this and what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: Is the main being *loaded*? Are you running in debug or release mode (affects which file `requirejs` tries to load)? What version of Durandal? As a non-related question, any reason you haven't upgraded to knockout 3?

Comment: Main is not loaded. Launched from VS in debug mode. Deployed as debug not release. Durandal 2.0.1. Because that's what Nuget gave me.

Comment: Sounds like the paths may be off now due to being localhost/Client vs the dev environment most likely being localhost?  Try fiddler and see what files are being asked for, that should give some more clues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC Durandal app only works in server root url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773144/mvc-durandal-app-only-works-in-server-root-url)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Directories are created to serve static content as far as I understand. ( Just a subfolder of another application ). As the StarterKit runs using MVC4/5 you need also ASP.NET support thus creating a normal application ( parallel to defaultapp ) should do the trick.

If you did that already that way maybe you're missing some files. Had a situation where some files weren't deployed ( eg. the views folder ). Double check if those are present.